# Что означает это выражение? sex = rep (levels (sex) [1], 2)

Tags: r, rstudio

Понятно, что следующее выражение как-то трансформирует переменную sex

`sex = rep (levels (sex) [1], 2)`

но что означает код

`[1], 2`

P.S.

Кстати, если посмотреть, что это выражение делает, то получается, что ничего:

`sex <- c (`f`,`m`,`f`,`f`,`m`,`m`)
 sex = rep (levels (sex) [1], 2)`

> NULL

что невозможно, учитывая что это фрагмент более общего кода (с фактором sex)

`new_data <- with (my_data, data.frame (sex = rep (levels(sex) [1], 2)))`

Comment: Ну функция `levels()` возвращает массив, откуда достается второй элемент `[1]` — этот элемент, и число `2` передаются в качестве аргумента функции `rep(elem, 2)` Больше ничего нельзя сказать по предоставленным данным.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном коде факторов вообще нету. Если `sex` все-таки сделать фактором, все работает.

```
> sex <- factor(c("f", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m"))
> sex
[1] f m f f m m
Levels: f m
> sex <- rep(levels(sex)[1], 2)
> sex
[1] "f" "f"
```